# Simple C# login with 3 attempts

Tags: c#, console, login-attempts

I need to create a simple C# Sharp program that takes userid and password as input (type string). After 3 wrong attempts user should be rejected.

I have started but I'm not sure how the logic should be properly done.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace UserId
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Type username");
            String UserId1 = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Type password");
            String Pass = Console.ReadLine();

            String UserIdCorrect = "test1";
            String PassCorrect = "password1";
            int MaxAttempts = 3;



            Console.ReadKey();

            if (UserId1 != UserIdCorrect && Pass != PassCorrect ) {
                MaxAttempts++;

            }


            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to [so], it sounds like a coursework, try to solve it by yourself first.

Comment: have you learned how to structure the flow of a program?

Comment: A couple pointers: what you are looking for is a `while` loop. Also, you need to keep current number of attempts and compare it with max attempts. You shouldn't be increasing `MaxAttempts`.

Comment: Here is a solution using `for` http://stackoverflow.com/a/36399680

Comment: @HebeleHododo: I'd rather put it into `for` loop (since we have **3** atempts): either we `break` the loop with the correct password or end the loop failing to login

Comment: @DmitryBychenko yup. That's nice as well.

Comment: Thanks  @HebeleHododo that helped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, even before writing a single line of code, try to think about naming conventions for a minute or two. This is like "putting foam on your face before having a shave. You can get a shave even without the shaving foam but the experience wouldn't be nice". Try this link for more info [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045(v=vs.110).aspx].

Now moving towards your question, if I have to only fulfill your requirement, this code will be suffice. Here I'm taking "valid" as an identifier for the correct credentials:

```
<code>
    //Login Attempts counter
    int loginAttempts = 0;

    //Simple iteration upto three times
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter username");
        string username = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter password");
        string password = Console.ReadLine();

        if (username != "valid" || password != "valid")
            loginAttempts++;
        else
            break;
    }

    //Display the result
    if (loginAttempts > 2)
        Console.WriteLine("Login failure");
    else
        Console.WriteLine("Login successful");

    Console.ReadKey();
</code>
```

Comment: Thanks @iSahilSharma that also answers my question and the advice is really helpful  :)

Comment: I wish I could give this more than one up vote. This answer was perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Just run the for loop 3 times and if still user enter the wrong entry than just disable the window .

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are a beginner. I've commented the code.

```
int maxAttempts = 3;

// looping n (maxAttempts) times
for(int i = 0; i < maxAttempts; i++)
{
    // get input and check it
}

// do what ever you want here.
// at least show up a message
```

Many ways. As HebeleHododo commented you could also use a while-loop and check with if-else if your maxAttempts is reached.

Comment: Loop of nothing is too cruel. What if I've run the routine by mistake? Just `return` with the appropriate message.

Comment: If the login has to fail after 3 tries, I would rather force the user to also close the app manually rather than pressing enter and it closes itself. Matter of taste. Either way a message should be for sure displayed. Edited to satisfy you ;)

Comment: Thanks @C4u it's done now and yeah I have just started working with C#